# Turning a folder into a module in Python

Tags: python, module, directory

I have a module in Python that is growing a tad out of hand.  I would like to segregate it into smaller files to better manage my code, but I would like it to seem as if nothing has changed.  To be concrete, suppose I have the classes `C1` and `C2` in `c.py`.  I would like to create a folder structure,

```
c/
    __init__.py
    c1.py    <--- class C1 in here
    c2.py    <--- class C2 in here
```

such that I can use the code in the following two ways

```
import c
c1 = c.C1()
c2 = c.C2()
```

and

```
from c import *


c1 = C1()
c2 = C2()
```

I've already got most of the way there;  if I define `__init__.py` as follows,

```
from c1 import *
from c2 import *
__all__ == []
```

then I can do use `c` in the first of the two ways.  How can I use `c` in the second fashion (preferably without enumerating all `C1` and `C2` in `__all__`)

Answer (score 0):

Skip the `__all__` statement in `__init__.py` and you will be able to use both methods.

Comment: That will result in module `c1` and `c2` being imported as well.  How can I make this not happen?

Comment: It will cause `from c import *`to have `C1` and `C2` imported, so that you can use commands like `c1 = C1()`.

Comment: Ohhh, I get what you mean. I guess you'll have to explicitly put them into `__all__` then.